# Dynamically creating buttons in javascript using for loop, and assigning properties.

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute, createelement

I am trying to use the below code to add buttons into the body of my page, the buttons appear, but none of the attributes display, it is a default button with no increase in size with font size, no text displayed, and no color.

```js
function createKeyboard()
 {
    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
     var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
     var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
     btn.setAttribute("id","btn"+nextChar);
     btn.setAttribute("innerHtml",nextChar);
     btn.setAttribute("value",nextChar);
     btn.setAttribute("text",nextChar);
     btn.setAttribute("font-size","14px");
     btn.setAttribute("background-color","#4CAF50");
     document.body.appendChild(btn);
     }
    };
```

When looking at the buttons using the console I can see the attributes are there, as shown below:

```html
    <button id="btnA" innerhtml="A" value="A" text="A" font-size="14px"        background-color="#4CAF50"></button>
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here, any ideas?

-Thanks

Comment: buttons don't have `.innerHTML`. You spelled that attribute wrong anyways. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: @PHPglue sure you aren't thinking of `<input>`? `<button>` can certainly have innerHTML

Comment: Nope, that is incorrect. Try to do some CSS styling on the button children. You won't be able to style things like that on a bunch of Browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is not an attribute, specially innerHTML.

```
btn.setAttribute("style","font-size:14px;background-color: #4CAF50");
btn.innerHTML = "A"
```

Comment: `btn.innerHTML` is going to be a problem on many a Browser. Use `btn.value`.

Comment: Well, `id` is a valid attribute. The only one.

Comment: If it is a form button, then type, disabled etc. are also HTML based attributes. All attributes are always valid not only id, but doesn't mean they would work in a desired way.

Comment: Kawadhiya21, thanks between the input from you and isaacdre I have it figured out. I have only been at this for a couple of weeks, a lot of trial and error on my part. Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 4):

1. The attributes "font-size" and "background-color" need to be in style="font-size:14px; background-color:#4CAF50;"
2. innerHTML make sure the HTML is caps
3. I'm not sure that "text" is a valid attribute for button

Did that fix anything? You're using quite a bunch of attributes that I'm pretty sure aren't valid.

EDIT: +1 Xufox's comment. Here is more on that:

For what you need to do, you'll need to have an understanding:

1. **HTML attributes**

   - Most common are id, class, href, src, style < Usually fellow developers like it better when you create a class and assign style to it via css. This is where your code `btn.setAttribute("id","btn"+nextChar);` works. Here is a link that goes over them a bit more: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp
2. **HTML DOM nodes** (nodes have properties <- what xufox was referring to.)

   - When the browser renders your HTML, it registers each element
     `<div>example element</div>` as a node that can be manipulated.
     Some common node properties are: innerHTML, style, id... notice the overlap? Yep, Editing element properties is easy with DOM node property manipulation. `btn.innerHTML = 'Wow, this is easy!';`

**Conclusion:** Try this, post any further questions

```
function createKeyboard()
{
   var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
   {
    var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.id = 'btn' + nextChar;
    btn.innerHTML = nextChar;
    btn.setAttribute("value", nextChar);
    btn.setAttribute("text",nextChar);
    btn.style.fontSize = "14px";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#4CAF50';
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
};
```

Even better than btn.style edits would be to add a class that was styled using css. But for the purpose of this conversation, I'll end it there.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a property, not an attribute. And it still needs to be set.

Comment: Agreed. Quite a bunch of invalid attributes.

Comment: Yes background color worked, not sure on font size as I am still trying to figure out how to get the nextChar variable to work with the format you specified. It is progress, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check this out. Just made it.

```js
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm, C, E, buttonMaker; // reuse on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){

doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
buttonMaker = function(alphaString, appendTo, clickFunc){
  var a = alphaString.split('');
  for(var i=0,b,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    b = C('input'); b.type = 'button'; b.value = a[i];
    b.addEventListener('click', clickFunc);
    appendTo.appendChild(b);
  }
  return appendTo;
}
var test = E('testOut');
function buttonClickHandler(){
  test.innerHTML += this.value;
}
buttonMaker('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', E('buttons'), buttonClickHandler);
E('clear').onclick = function(){ // can't reuse without writing over
  test.innerHTML = '';
}

});
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
#buttons>input{
  font-size:14pt; background-color:#4CAF50;
}
#testOut{
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='buttons'></div>
    <div id='testOut'></div>
    <input type='button' id='clear' value='clear' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```